# Joomla admin redirects to https

Tags: administrator, ssl, https

I wasn't attending one of my websites for 2 weeks, after that and without doing anything at all (like installing or uninstalling anything).

When I tried to login to my website it redirects to `https` (I have never enabled this option and it is disabled in `config.php`) and it stops there. I have done a lot of tricks but nothing worked.

Could anyone resolve this problem?

Comment: Maybe check in the `.htaccess` file to see if a redirection has been added there

Comment: @NeilRobertson : I disabled it completely, but the problem was not solved

Comment: Is this for the admin, front-end, or both?  If front-end, what login component/module/plugins are you using?

Comment: No, it is only backend and front end works smoothly

Answer (score 1):

you can disable loading https by doing this

1. Go to global configuration
2. then go to the Server tab
3. now in the server settings you can select Force HTTPS to none

Hope it will help you

Comment: The problem is, this problem has nothing to do with this configuration, as I mentioned before

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It was because of one of my modules in the admin page. I went to the database and I disabled the admin panel modules one by one. And after all I figured out what was the problem. Thank you everyone for caring!

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't you and it wasn't a hacker I would contact my host if I were you.  Maybe they installed something like Let's Encrypt and forced all sites to use https?

Comment: They did everything even changing the server completely but it wasn't solved

Comment: I think it was a hacker.